# Atributos de herdeiros com prototype não aparecem em reflection Javascript

Tags: javascript, herança, propriedade, protótipo

Eu tenho a classe `Animal` que tem algumas propriedades que são `enumerable: true`, ou seja, posso lista-las via reflection usando `for..in`.

Então eu tenho a classe `Coelho` que tem o atributo `cor`. Como coelho herda de `Animal` via `prototype`, posso chamar a function `Descrever()`. Acontece que a **cor** do coelho não é listada no reflection.

O que eu estou fazendo errado? Qual é a possível solução?

Código funcionando no JSBin aqui: http://jsbin.com/cuyaci/1/edit?js,console,output

```
console.clear();
var Animal = function(nome,comida){
   var _nome=nome||'';
   var _comida=comida||'';
   var self=this;

  Object.defineProperty(this,"Nome",{
                        get:function(){return _nome;},
                        set:function(value){_nome=value;},
                          enumerable:true
                        });


  Object.defineProperty(this,"Comida",{
                        get:function(){return _comida;},
                        set:function(value){_comida=value;},
                          enumerable:true
                        });

this.Descrever=function(){
  for(var prop in self)
    if(typeof self[prop]!=='function')
  console.log(self[prop]);
    };
};

var Coelho = function(cor){
  this.cor=cor||"Branco";

};
Coelho.prototype=new Animal('coelho','legumes');

var a = new Animal("vaca",'grama');
var c = new Coelho('azul');

a.Descrever();
c.Descrever();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que o problema aqui é você estar a usar `var self=this;` e a limitar a referencia na nova instância.

Se mudar o `self` para `this` dentro desse `for` o `this` vai apontar para a instância certa.:

```
this.Descrever=function(){
  for(var prop in this)
    if(typeof this[prop]!=='function')
  console.log(this[prop]);
    };
};
```

Já vai funcionar como quer/deve.
**Exemplo: http://codepen.io/sergiocrisostomo/pen/myJKJY**

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa invocar o construtor de animal no construtor do Coelho.

Corrigi o seu exemplo (e adequei a conveção das funções em letra minuscula) aqui; http://jsbin.com/dikebekafa/2/edit

Comment: Eu, pelo menos, estou curioso para maiores informações :D

Comment: A explicação é que não só você precisa atribuir uma instancia da classe pai ao `prototype` da filha, mas além disso invocar o construtor do pai, que não é invocado automaticamente. Talvez esse post ajude mais; https://www.exratione.com/2011/05/inheritance-and-initialization-in-nodejs/